# OpenGL heightmap terrain render does not draw

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, terrain

I have a bitmap map that created from a dted file. I want to use that bitmap and create a 3d terrain render. I am trying to do it with vertex vectors but I couldn't reach my goal at all. Here is my paintGL code:

```
void render::paintGL(){
glLoadIdentity();
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glTranslatef(0,0,-100);
for(int z=0;z<dted.width()-1;z++){
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    for(int x = 0; x<dted.height()-1; x++){
        glColor3f(matrix[x][z], matrix[x][z], matrix[x][z]);
        glVertex3f(x, matrix[x][z], -z);
        //vertex0 ends here

        glColor3f(matrix[x+1][z], matrix[x+1][z], matrix[x+1][z]);
        glVertex3f(x+1, matrix[x+1][z], -z);
        //vertex1 ends here

        glColor3f(matrix[x][z+1], matrix[x][z+1], matrix[x][z+1]);
        glVertex3f(x, matrix[x][z+1], -z-1);
        //vertex2 ends here

        glColor3f(matrix[x+1][z+1], matrix[x+1][z+1], matrix[x+1][z+1]);
        glVertex3f(x+1, matrix[x+1][z+1], -z-1);
        //vertex3 ends here


    }
    glEnd();
}}
```

I had to write the code instead of copy-paste because of internet issues. So there may be things that I forgot but I did my best. Let me explain the variables and other things above:

dted is the dted image I created and I set boundaries from that images width and height values. matrix is a 2d matrix that holds the elevation values I get from the pre-created dted image pixels.

After all the code above I couldn't manage to render the terrain. I don't know if it renders the terrain but it just doesn't show me or it's not rendering at all. If you explain where is my mistake and suggest a solution for it, it would be great.

Sorry for the grammar mistakes if I did any, and I hope I did explain my problem well. If the code I provided is not sufficient, feel free to mention that and I can write the other parts down too.

Have a nice day.

Edit: Ok I got a fresh news over here. I have managed to draw a plain after getting over some control with mouse issues. However, when I try to get amplitude, it shows nothing. That because of the too much amplitude I guess, but when I divide it by a constant like 15 the same plain shows up again. Is this because of I used `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` ?

Comment: First, make sure you are capable of drawing: start with one triangle at a hardcoded location. Second: `matrix` values are between 0 and 1? They should if you input them to `glColor3f`. Can you please check that?

Comment: I checked it and saw that it wasn't. However, I divided it to 255 (pixels values were from 0 to 255) and it is still showing nothing. By the way I already draw a cube and it showed well.

Comment: Now you must check your camera: is it too far? Is the plane perpendicular to it (so that becomes just a thin line)? Try exaggerating Y values with a multiplier

Comment: I have set up a mouse event for that, that zoom outs when right click and zooms in when left click, that changes the translatef function's z value. I did multiplied the amplitude of Y by 15 (matrix[x][z]*15) and unsuprisingly I couldn't see it. Do you think the problem is the camera?

Comment: Yes, it could be pointed elsewhere

Comment: Well, I don't know opengl well but as I understood from the cube I created for the trial, camera is centered to the origin by default, and translatef function is just placing the rendered item to that coordinat system. That's why I'm changing the translatef function's parameters. That's why I am trying to create the map chunk by chunk. So I'm started to think it is not rendering it at all. Have an idea for that?

Comment: Switch to `GL_POINTS` with `glPointSize(50)`

Comment: It diddn't help either.

Comment: Restart with the cube... And draw it near your points

Comment: I did it and it rendered well.

Comment: What happens if you use "0" instead of your `matrix[][]`?

Comment: Same as the beggining. Draws nothing.

Comment: Ok I got a fresh news over here. I have managed to draw a plain after getting over some control with mouse issues. However, when I try to get amplitude, it shows nothing. That because of the too much amplitude I guess, but when I divide it by a constant like 15 the same plain shows up again. Is this because of I used GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP ?

Comment: It's hard to make out the problem without the rest of your rendering code, but one thing: i believe your indices might be a problem: you look from 0 to width-1, but than access x and (x+1), which can thus become width.

Comment: @Knowleech indices are fine, no overflow there

Comment: I have managed to render something but it seems to be too big to see and no matter how far I zoom out, it does not seems like an understandable rendered object. For an angled view I added code this: 'glRotatef(45,0,1,0)'

Comment: You said: "but when I divide it by a constant like 15 the same plain shows up again" Could it be, that you were doing an interger-Divison and got rounded to zero? Be sure to write " matrix[][] / 15.0f "

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys. I finally am able to do it. I couldn't do it without you guys' help. Thanks alot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the other guys who are looking for solution at this: Make sure that your glFrustum's zNear parameter is far enough to see things. Mine were to close and when I increased it, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your rendering code seems strange: You build your tri strip with degenerated triangles and might access data which isn't there. I guessed the rest of your approach and tried to fix your method. Try this:

```
void render::paintGL(){
  glLoadIdentity();
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glTranslatef(0,0,-100);
  for(int z = 0; z < dted.width() - 2; z++) {
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    for(int x = 0; x < dted.height() - 1; x++){
        glColor3f(matrix[x][z], matrix[x][z], matrix[x][z]);
        glVertex3f(x, matrix[x][z], -z);
        //vertex0 ends here

        glColor3f(matrix[x][z + 1], matrix[x][z + 1], matrix[x][z + 1]);
        glVertex3f(x, matrix[x][z + 1], -z - 1);
        //vertex1 ends here

    }
    glEnd();
}}
```

Other than this, triangle strips are fine. If you still don't see anything, follow the suggestion by Sga and use GL_POINTS. Then fix you camera/other rendering code until you see them.

Comment: I have managed to render something but it seems to be too big to see and no matter how far I zoom out, it does not seems like an understandable rendered object. For an angled view I added code this: 'glRotatef(45,0,1,0)'

Comment: Is triangle strip necessary? Can I use polygon or quads? The fit more to my purpose as I want to render it chunk by chunk like rendering a 2d image pixel by pixel.

Comment: The rendering code I posted is rather minimalistic and should work. If the geometry is "extreme" check the values you get by your matrix classes. As test, you can (again) replace all "matrix[][]" with zero, or any other constant. If it still does not work, check the matrices you are using as modelview and projection. I find it strange, that you call glLoadIdentity() before you call glMatrixMode.

Comment: ... and, by the way, TRIANGLE_STRIP is what you want to use. QUAD or POLYGON are dreprecated in modern graphics, and is good to avoid these. For your unterstanding, the aquivalent to a pixel is not the quad (or triangle) but the Vertex. The triangles specify the connections, e.g. the structure on which to interpolate.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys. I finally am able to do it. I couldn't do it without you guys' help. Thanks alot...